# docker nginx django gunicorn not serving static files in production

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx

Trying to deploy website with nginx + gunicorn + docker + django. But ngingx isn't serving static files. Following are the configurations:

Django project structure

[image]

settings file production.py

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

"""STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)"""


STATIC_ROOT = "/app/forex/static/admin/"
```

Docker file for nginx

```
FROM nginx:1.19.0

COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

nginx configurations

```
upstream django {
    server website:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
    }
    
    location /media/ {
        alias /app/media/;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /app/forex/static/admin/;
    }
}
```

Gunicorn docker file

```
FROM python:3


ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000:8000

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --settings=forex.settings.production

CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--workers", "3", "forex.wsgi:application", "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=forex.settings.production"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
    website:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile.app
        env_file:
          - env
        container_name: website_container_8
    nginx:
        build: ./nginx
        volumes:
            - static:/app/forex/static/admin/
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        depends_on:
            - website
volumes:
  static:
```

FROM nginx container, it isn't copying static files.
[image]

What do I need to change to make it working?

Comment: You are mounting a static named volume, which is empty, where is your static folder on your host?

Comment: @C1sc0 What is empty ```volumes: static:``` do you mean this?

Comment: In your dockerfile you are not copying anything from your local static folder to the image `/app/forex/static/admin/` this path. At least `RUN python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --settings=forex.settings.production` this line does nothing

Comment: Do you mean that I need to run ```collectstatic``` from development and then copy those files with Docker ```COPY``` command to be able to copy them to desired location?

Comment: No, it should work like this too, but the error is there

Comment: So how do I need to make changes now?

Comment: In your docker compose put `volumes:
            - static:/app/forex/static/admin/` under your app container too

Comment: It says ```volumes``` must be a mapping.

Comment: check my answer, it is too long, to post it here :D

Comment: But the question is, why would ```website``` service that is primarily running gunicorn and comes later in request processing cycle, should know about volumes when they are being served by ```nginx``` container?

Comment: You are generating the static contet that nginx has to serve to you with your `website` (Gunicorn docker file) container, at `RUN python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --settings=forex.settings.production` this line, you can move it to nginx (by build a multi stage dockerfile) that way you don't have to share folders between conainers

Comment: static is served from here: `location /static/ {
        alias /app/forex/static/admin/;
    }`

Comment: your web app (gunicorn) is:  `location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your files are located at your website container, you need to share it, with the nginx container:

```
services:
    website:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile.app
        env_file:
          - env
        container_name: website_container_8
        volumes:
            - static:/app/forex/static/admin/ #<-- you want to share this
    nginx:
        build: ./nginx
        volumes:
            - static:/app/forex/static/admin/ #<-- with this folder
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        depends_on:
            - website
volumes:
  static: #<-- you can do it through this
```